# PowerShell event handling for WebBrowser object

Tags: powershell, event-handling, webbrowser-control

I want to create a simple Userform with a WebBrowser object in PowerShell to browse one specific URL. The website located at that URL opens some hyperlinks as popups which causes these links to open in a new InternetExplorer window.

Instead I would like to catch these popups with the NewWindow-event and somehow create another tab with a new WebBrowser instance.

First of all I'm stuck at firing the event correctly it seems. The following code runs fine so far, but the event won't get fired at the right time. Instead I get multiple notification popups after I close my userform (number depending on how many new windows I opened).

```
$Browser_NewWindow = {
    $(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).Popup("Event fired correctly")
}

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
$Form.Text = "MiniBrowser"
$Form.Controls.Add($Browser)

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Browser -EventName NewWindow -Action $Browser_NewWindow
$Browser.Navigate("http://www.bing.com")
$Form.Width = 900
$Form.Height = 900
$Browser.Top = 0
$Browser.Left = 0
$Browser.Width = 880
$Browser.Height = 890

$DialogResult = $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: PowerShell does not fire form events, the form does and you need code on that event handler to do other stuff. This is not a PowerShell issue, this is a UX/UI issue with that browser control. Please look at the MS docs details of that control to set your expectations.  You are just opening the Bing.com page and even in default IE, it will not pop a new tab for a clicked link. To get a new tab in real IE, you have to use a Crtl+Click for that. If you use your from and go to links and use Crtl+Click, the New Tab option is grayed out.  You need a tabbed from UX/UI, to display new links.

Comment: For example a pre-built tab control for forms. [Advanced WinForms TabControl](https://www.syncfusion.com/winforms-ui-controls/tabcontrol) or these resource for WinForm tabbed and PowerShell, ['powershell tabbed form control'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+tabbed+form+control%27&t=h_&ia=web)